# Why I can't see my smoke in render?

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation

I'm trying to add smoke to my scene, but it didn't work well. I can see smoke in viewport (in very bad quality and always black blinking, but still). When I'm trying to render it, I didn't see any smoke in scene, even if I made white smoke color.

Here's my [file](https://pasteall.org/blend/256d2f2356df445997bc330efcf9dbe2).

P.S. I checked material of domain, it's not empty.

Comment: I had the same problem fixed by changing the cache directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possible solutions.

You can change the Density factor on your "Smoke Domain Material" from 5.0 to higher (here 99.0):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Another solution: Change the "density" of the emitter. you have it set to default of 1.0. Try 2.0:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works!

Comment: @Сергей -- another solution: Change the "density" of the emitter.  you have it set to default of 1.0.  Try 2.0.